# How to change label text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is div tag

```
<div>
    <label>some text 1</label>
    <label>another text 1</label>
</div>
<button>button</button>
```

Whenever I click on the button, I will add the div tag. when the next div tag is added, it should change the digit in the label text.

For example: In the first div, it should be `1` and in the next div it should be `2`.

I am getting the label text using

```
var labelValue = $('div').find('label').map(function() {
   return $(this).text().replace(/\d/,2);
}).get();
```

What I want is to change digit in the label text to 2.

I am getting the value but the label value is not getting changed in the html.

How to get the updated label value?

Sorry if there are any mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('div').find('label').each(function(){
 $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\d/,2));
});
```

Comment: Can also be done like this: `$(this).text(function(i,t){ return t.replace(/\d/,2);});`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    $('div:eq(0)').clone().insertAfter('div:last').find('label').filter(function(e) {
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\d/, $("div").length));
    });
})
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ae9owggn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

maybe that one you want [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y9ug9j7j/1/)

```
<div id="show_divz">
    <div id="div_1">
        <label>some text 1</label>
        <label>another text 1</label>
    </div>
</div>
<button>button</button>
```

in js

```
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
    var getId = $(this).prev().find('div').last().attr('id');
    getId = getId.split('_');
    $("#show_divz").append('<div id="div_'+(parseInt(getId[1])+1)+'"><label>some text '+(parseInt(getId[1])+1)+'</label><label>another text '+(parseInt(getId[1])+1)+'</label> </div>');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

make id for button and trigger the click event to achive it..
*try this..*

```
 <div>
    <label>some text 1</label>
    <label>another text 1</label>
    </div>
    <button id="btn">button</button>
   <script> 
    $('#btn').click(function(){
      $('div').find('label').each(function(){
     $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\d/,2));
    }); }); </script>
```

here is the fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/Sarathv15/0jbq7em3/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be a help,

```
var count = 0;

$("#btn").click(function() {
    count++;
    $("#lbl").html(count);
}

</script>
<div><label id="lbl">1</label></div>

<button id="btn" type="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to replace the HTML here use

```
$(this).html("new value");
```